# NSLog fixing missing value/crash?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

My app imports likes from Facebook using `Social.framework` and `ACAccount`. I save the Facebook account identifier to `NSUserDefaults` so that the app can automatically import new likes on subsequent launches. The first import works fine. The problem is with re-instantiating the `ACAccount` on subsequent launches.

So I have a `facebookAccount` getter that looks like this:

```
- (ACAccount *)facebookAccount {
    if(!_facebookAccount) {
        ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
        NSString *accountIdentifier = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:SWFacebookAccountIdentifierKey];

        if(accountIdentifier)
            _facebookAccount = [accountStore accountWithIdentifier:accountIdentifier];

    }
    return _facebookAccount;
}
```

This returns a somehow incomplete `ACAccount` object:

```
type:(null)
identifier: B6E94A67-AF94-408F-A618-6CD4D78564DC
accountDescription: Facebook
username: samvermette@gmail.com
objectID: x-coredata://589C098E-F829-4284-841B-EE4A0003FF21/Account/p2
enabledDataclasses: {(
    )}
enableAndSyncableDataclasses: {(
    )}
properties: {
    fullname = "Sam Vermette";
    uid = 716308665;
}
parentAccount: (null)
owningBundleID:(null)
```

This gets logged from the method that ends up using this object. As you can see the `type` value is `null`, which makes my app throw the following exception:

> NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Invalid account type for this request

Now, the strangest thing is that if I add `NSLog(_facebookAccount)` right before the `return` in my getter, the `type` key is not null and my app doesn't crash. I realize that NSLog fixing this may be a hint at something that's wrong with my code, but I can't figure out what exactly. Any ideas?

Comment: you have to retain _facebookAccount and if you are writing NSLog after return, this will show garbage values as it has returned.

Comment: @fibnochi He is using ARC, so he cant use retain. Indeed Sam, you can store it in some ivar or global variable and then try printing it.

Comment: facebookAccount is set as a strong property, so it is retained. The problem was that I need to keep the accountStore around as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem ended up being that ARC was auto-releasing the account store, which owns the `ACAccount` objects.

I fixed this by assigning my account store to a strong property

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) ACAccountStore *accountStore;
```